# Никак не хочет устанавливаться Denwer

Tags: denwer

Каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь установить "джентльменский набор разработчика", выскакивает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю, что и думать.

Comment: denwer уж умер давно. одно старье тамюю php 5.3, когда на дворе php7... юзай openserver

Comment: Windows я недавно обновлял с 8 до 10. На старой винде было то же самое. Как написал софт, делать пробовал - ноль эффекта.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать, как тебе написал софт. Скорее всего у тебя винда корявая)

Comment: Правильно! Ставь линукс :)) А по сабжу, откати `PATH` до первоначального

Comment: Linux вещь , причём даже если заядлый виндузятник то Линукс Минт как раз для таких